# Determine, through investigation, the equations of the lines that have a slope of $2$ and that intersect the quadratic function $f(x)=x(x-6)$

Tags: functions, quadratics, slope

Determine, through investigation, the equations of the lines that have a slope of $2$ and that intersect the quadratic function $f(x)=x(x-6)$.
once; twice; never.

http://prntscr.com/domblp

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: the lines with slope $2$ have equation $y=2x+q$. Try intersecting them with your curve and determine $q$ appropriately.

I won't go further in my answer, since you should provide what you tried first ;)

Comment: You're welcome.